# HTML form vaidation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate an html form using javascript the code is bellow

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function   validate(){
        if(document.form1.thbox.checked)
            {
                alert("yes");
            }
            else
                alert("no");
    }

    </script>
        <form name="form1" method="get">
            <input type="checkbox" name="thebox"/>
            <input type="button" value="press me" onclick="validate()"/>
           </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

when ever I try to press on button nothing works 
Can someone please tell me why is that?
Thank you

Comment: As a side note, the "classic" way to validate a form is to use the `onsubmit` attribute in the `<form>` tag: `<form ... onsubmit="validate()">`. And in your `validate` function, you either return `true` to allow the submission, or `false` to cancel it. In this case, the button should be of type `submit` instead of `button`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `if(document.form1.thbox.checked)` to `if(document.form1.thebox.checked)` You have missed **e** in `thebox`

http://jsfiddle.net/eJhzf/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because `checked` is not a valid property of `undefined`:

HTML:

```
name="thebox"
```

Javascript:

```
form1.thbox.checked
```

Notice the missing **e**, so, it should be:

```
form1.thebox.checked
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
   if ( document.form1.thebox.checked == false )
{
    alert ( "Please select check box." );

}
           else {
              // your code or message
          }
```

and use thebox instead of thbox